# Is posible define a function (+= var amount) in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm studying functional programming in racket, and a question test said:

In Java we can increment a varible using `x += 10;`

Can we define a function in Racket `(+= var amount)` with the same meanings of Java?

I'm not really sure, but I think no because I can't modify a variable with a function in racket.

Like:

```
(define myvar 10)

(+= myvar 1)

myvar
```

I'm keep getting 10, when I type `myvar` in the drracket console

Comment: Not with a function. Try a [macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html)

Comment: You can't write such a function in Java either.

Comment: really? but what about when you use `int i = 10;` and then `i+=10;`?, you got 20 @molbdnilo

Comment: @Dogo-San Yes, but you can't write a *function* that does the same. Try `void increment(int x) { x = x + 10; }`.

Comment: @Dogo-San, If you try to write Scheme programs like Java, you're going to end up very frustrated and probably dislike Scheme. The languages are very different and each encourages a very different style of programming. I recommend you forget what you know about other languages and approach Scheme with a fresh state of mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically `x += 5` are short for `x = x + 5` in most Algol languages. In Java I'm sure you cannot do what you are asking for. eg.

```
public static void method plusEqual(int binding, int increment) {
  binding = binding + increment;
}
```

However in Scheme and Racket you can. Since the full form is `(set! binding (+ binding argument))` I'm suggesting `+set!`

```
(define-syntax +set!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ binding increment)
     (set! binding (+ binding increment)))))

(define test 10)
(+set! test 5)
test ; ==> 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a function to do this.

You can define a macro that expands to `(set! var (+ var amount))` though, and that'll do it!